# How to expose a js variable in global scope with laravel mix (webpack)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I am using `Laravel 5.4`'s `mix` tool to build and combine my `AngularJS 1` files. Here's my `webpack.mix.js` for Laravel:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js');
mix.combine('resources/assets/js/directives/*', 'public/js/directives.js');
```

Here is the app defination:

```
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    //...
]);
```

and here is a directive

```
myApp.directive('navigation', function () {
    return {
        templateUrl: 'app/modules/layouts/nav.html',
        replace: true
    };
});
```

The problem is when I build the files and includes them on html I get the error

```
ReferenceError: myApp is not defined
```

from the compiled `diretives.js` file.

I figure out that as `mix` uses `webpack` for compiling, and `webpack` enclose each js file's content in a anonymous function so my `myApp` variable is only accessible in the compiled `app.js` file, not in the global scope. When I manually remove the anonymous function from compiled `app.js` file it works just fine.

So I was wondering if there is a way to make the `myApp` variable globally accessible though `Laravel`'s `mix` configuration?

Comment: Though the correct way would be to register various angular components to module is using `angular.module('myApp')` as a getter. never pollute global namespace..

Comment: can you please elaborate @pankajparkar

Comment: See how Laravel does it in its starter code: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/v5.4.21/resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js (stuff like `window._ = require('lodash');`)

Comment: @ceejayoz yours should be an answer. It made my day

Answer (score -2):

Try inlining the myapp function in HTML script tags instead of putting it in a separate JavaScript file.

Comment: I understand it would work and working as well, but I am trying to figure out how this can be done by `laravel-mix` i.e `webpack`

Comment: your answer sould be a comment.